# Adding Custom class in nested <ul> in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, navbar

I am new in wordpress, Please give me an idea to add custom class in  in wordpress. Below is my code. Here class="sub-menu" is auto class created by wordpress.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pos-right navbar-left">
     <li class="mega-dropdown active">
        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle menu-item">HOME</a>    
     </li>

    <li class="has-dropdown">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle menu-item">ABOUT US</a>
            <ul class ="sub-menu">
                <li> <a href="page-about.html">our story</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="page-chefs.html">our chefs</a> </li>
            </ul>
    </li>
```